# Php file are not parsed by fastcgi in nginx

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, php5, fastcgi

I m new to nginx my server block is

```
server {
    listen 25552;
    server_name *.example.com;
    root /usr/share/myPackage;
    rewrite ^/$ /index.php permanent;

        location ~ ((\.php$)|(^/(status)$)) {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       }
       access_log  /var/log/nginx/console-access.log;
}
```

Using browser i m able to get status 200 while hit my url - www.example.com:25552/index.php and same status for other php file but nothing is shown in the page. While i try to change the url and i am able to get my html,js and image file on my browser. What i think is that my php file are not getting parsed pls help me .... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I m not passing all fastcgi_params i followed [this link](http://wiki.nginx.org/PHPFcgiExample) help me to figure out my problem

Comment: Confirming that this worked for me. After an update where I carefully integrated updated config files, I had blank screen on any PHP file, no error messages or logs, HTTP status 200 OK. I was missing two lines in /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params . I updated using that link and it worked. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure PHP-FPM is listening on 127.0.0.1:9000 and not another socket. Without knowing more about the server, I can't tell you specifically where to look.

Comment: this is my access-log
for php file - HTTP/1.1" 200 5 "
for html file - HTTP/1.1" 200 640 "
for images - HTTP/1.1" 200 663073 " it varies with diffrent images
and yes it listening 
/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/host-stats.conf:listen = 127.0.0.1:9000

Comment: If PHP files "weren't being parsed" you would probably get raw PHP code as output. Do you have anything in your nginx error log (you didn't show one in your nginx config there) or PHP error log?

Comment: their was no nginx error